# Django all auth create userprofile with signup form

Tags: python, django, profile

I am trying to create a user profile.
The database row gets created, also the ID is correct (one-to-one relation).

All other data is not being stored.
For example: The `counter_announcements_approved` cell is always filled with NULL, instead of `222`.

Why is that?

```
class CustomSignupImmobilienbetreiber(SignupForm):
    first_name = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Vornamen")
    last_name = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Nachnamen")
    company_name = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Firma/Unternehmen")
    telephone_number = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Telefonnr.")
    street = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Straße")
    city = d_forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, label="Stadt")
    state = d_forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, label="Bundesstaat", required=True)
    gewerbeanmeldung = d_forms.FileField()

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        #profile, created = Immobilienbetreiber.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        user.user_type = 1
        user.is_active = 0
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.company_name = self.cleaned_data['company_name']
        user.telephone_number = self.cleaned_data['telephone_number']
        user.street = self.cleaned_data['street']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']

        profile = user.immobilienbetreiber_profile
        profile.gewerbeanmeldung = self.cleaned_data['gewerbeanmeldung']
        profile.counter_announcements_approved = 222


        user.save()
        profile.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Uppdate with model.py file.

Comment: `profile, created = immobilienbetreiber_profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` and then rest of the code. But first save the user object and then write above code.

Answer (score 0):

Save your user before the profile fields. Or dit you save it elsewhere?